# Do you load before paying?

Tags: jamaica

If you land on a space that requires payment, do you load resources before making the payment, or the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you cannot load and move at the same moment, and as payment can only happen after a move, the problem you describe never occurs.
First you make the morning action (move and eventually pay *or* load) **then** the evening action (move and eventually pay *or* load).

it's explained on the "island" #2 (Action Types) in [the rules](http://www.gameworks.ch/2010/pdf/jamaica_rules.pdf).